# Make clothes follow only part of the mesh and not the entire mesh's movement

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, pose-mode

I'm animating a voxel character I made for a game.

I created two different meshes: the character and his clothes which should be applied over. The character is already fully rigged with all bones which move correctly.

The actual problem is: I can't place the clothes over the character in a way that, when animating, they follow the body correctly.

I actually tried parenting the clothes to the armature and then using the data transfer modifier - it works because the clothes follow the armature when moving it but, when rotating or doing any transformation to the bones, they move along the bones without any reason. Also, it seems that they deform even in a normal T-pose, without a reason.

Take a look.

This is how it appears in the voxel editor, with his clothes on (but the clothes are two different meshes in Blender, obviously).

[image: Normal look in MagicaVoxel]

This is when clothes have a "data transfer" modifier in Blender. As you can see, they get a bit distorted (especially the front).

[image: Clothes with data transfer modifier]

With the data transfer modifier, even when simply moving a leg, everything moves along with it too, without any reason.

[image: Animating with data transfer modifier]

I understand that Blender doesn't know that clothes shouldn't move along with the legs.

How should I handle this situation? Is it related to weight painting or to the data transfer modifier I added? I read about pinning clothes but I don't understand if that could be useful in my situation or not.

Thanks and sorry for the silly question.